# Is there a python function or attribute to authenticate while scraping from an internal website(i.e work)

Tags: python, request, urllib

```
    import urllib
    import bs4

    url ="https://autoflow-cascade-na.amazon.com/DCA1/shiftplan/b9668119-6bd7-4db9-95d1-8516fc03812a"
    username = 'user'
    password = '!pass!'
    p = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()

    p.add_password(None, url, username, password)

    handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(p)
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
```

This is the error i am getting 
ValueError: AbstractBasicAuthHandler does not support the following scheme: 'Negotiate'

Comment: Whether or not you need to authenticate is determined by the service you connect to, not anything in the code that does the connecting.

Comment: i do have to authenticate, so for websites that needs authentication how would you go about it? newbie in python, apology if it sounds dumb

Comment: Then your title is completely misrepresenting your question, which is *how* to authenticate, not how to *bypass* authentication.

Comment: i mean if there is a way to bypass it then thats even better but i was scrolling through a lot of other answers and if the website uses authentication the answer i was seeing was i probably cant but i did change the question